# Tornar visível um textbox ao selecionar um radiobutton

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Com o código abaixo abaixo eu consigo fazer esse procedimento porém tenho que clicar no botão. Parece que ele preciso de um *refresh* para funcionar

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="pesquisa" /> Teste
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="pesquisa"/> Teste2
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

C#:

```
if (RadioButton1.Checked == true)
{
    TextBox1.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Usaria javascript para isso

Comment: Certo, Obrigado pela dica amigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a propriedade `AutoPostBack` para que a página processe as alterações:

`AutoPostBack="True"`

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="pesquisa" AutoPostBack="True" /> Teste
```

Também é possível alterar pela janela `Properties` do visual studio.

Mas, acredito que o recomendável seja fazer por javascript mesmo, que evita o postback.

Comment: Perfeito  Rovann,  muito Obrigado.

Comment: por nada, disponha =]